# My dog builds a bed out of my pillows and other things off my bed when I'm out

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, separation-anxiety

When I go out without my dog, she takes my pillows and other things off my bed and places them around her dog bed in the living room. She has even removed doonas off the bed. She will take my dressing gowns. She will sometimes put them on the couch.

For some background, she's a greyhound, she sleeps with me and is allowed on the lounges and beds. She also cries when I leave the house without her.

She was bred to race and spent her first two years at a greyhound trainers. When she didn't run fast enough she was taken, with her sister, to the vet to be put to sleep. There's a big problem with the greyhound racing industry where we live. She wasn't used to human companionship. [Some more info about her here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17419/issues-with-their-hound-growling-when-theyre-disturbed-when-sleeping).

She is never left alone. There's always someone home with her. I make a habit of closing my bedroom door when I'm going out without her.

I'm wondering what I can do to help her stop this, apart from closing the bedroom door.

*Bed building villain*[image]

Comment: I'd be interested in whether she prefers things with your personal scent (like your pillow or clothes) or if any soft item is equally preferred by her (like a random pillow on the couch).

Comment: @Elmy she prefers them with my scent

Comment: Could be an expression of seperation anxiety. I'll do some research tomorrow but from what I understand it's quite hard to "cure", if that's possible at all...

Comment: @Elmy yep I think it's related to separation anxiety

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is so adorable! (If annoying.)

I'd try giving your dog its own soft things, so maybe it will prefer those instead, and leave your bedroom alone. I've heard that greyhounds in particular get attached to plush dog toys, and sometimes carry them all around the house, so you might try giving your dog those too. It could be that your dog isn't actually trying to make a bed at all, but it is bored and gathering up its plush "toys." So you might also calm this behavior by having it played with while you're gone, or playing with it to tire it out before you leave.

And of course, I'd also keep the door closed. Once it's gotten used to these alternatives, it may prefer them, and then you might be able to leave your door open.